# Query regarding kubectl export variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables, sh, kubectl

I have following requirement in my code. I have to pass the variable as an argument to running pod using kubectl and then export the variable in pod's shell.

`$ export var="value"`

`$ echo $var`

`value`

`$ kubectl exec -it pod-0 -- /bin/bash -c "export var2=$var; echo $var2"`

The above command doesn't return "value" for var2.

Question : How to assign the variable which are passed as commandline parameter to kubectl command.

Comment: Prefix $var2 with a \.

Comment: @Cyrus can you put is as an answer?